# WSO2 Siddhi DynamoDB Store Extension

Tags: wso2, amazon-dynamodb, wso2-streaming-integrator

WSO2 siddhi currently doesn't have the extension for Amazon DynamoDB Store. Is there any possibility to connect DynamoDB as a storage backend for siddhi events?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no connector for Amazon DynamoDB. Also AFAIK there is no REST API to interact with DynamoDB, only SDKs. If there is a REST API we might me able to use HTTP extension to connect with DynamoDB. However this is currently in roadmap and released in the future. If the requirement is urgent you can write your own DynamoDB store extension using java-SDK. [Here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Writing+Custom+Siddhi+Extensions#WritingCustomSiddhiExtensions-siddhi-store) is the guide for extension creation. You can refer [MongoDB](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-store-mongodb) store implementation.